# Url rewrite angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url

so in my angularjs project i'm trying to change my url from

> http:/localhost/(project name)/#/home?ref=(page name) to
>
> http:/localhost/(project name)/home/(page name)

i have added url rewrite in iis.

[image: Url Rewrite snap shot]

also i have added html5mode true and base url,now when i try to run my project
all my resource files,app files points to

> localhost/app/controllers/controllers.js instead of
>
> localhost/(project name)/app/controllers/controllers.js..

now if i try to add my project name in base url it add project name twice like this,

> localhost/(project name)/(project name)/app/controllers/controllers.js

Can some one please tell me where i'm wrong?or why is this not working?

Thank you.